# undefined method `cmd' when installing a custom brew formula

Tags: ruby, qt, homebrew

I am creating a [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) formula:

```
class Pouet < Formula
  desc "A basic command line application written with Qt"
  homepage "https://github.com/MartinDelille/pouet"
  url "https://github.com/MartinDelille/pouet"
  version "0.1"
  sha256 "d4222bde4c798bc4d7f0a5566079d9095d4e4996bc53fe8fc76e63325aa0e71c"
  depends_on "qt" # => :build

  def install
    system "qmake", "pouet.pro"
    system "make"
    bin.install "pouet"
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}/pouet"
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I have the following error when trying to install it:

```
$ brew install pouet
==> Installing pouet from martindelille/tap
==> Downloading https://github.com/MartinDelille/pouet
Already downloaded: /Users/martin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/e2994828582a29cbbcc10eac093db7f4c95aab2139f30033de5ed3ed3a3f4ab9--pouet
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:206:in `rescue in <main>': undefined method `cmd' for #<ChecksumMismatchError:0x00007fcad2a0cae0> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:183:in `<main>'
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/sandbox-exec -f /private/tmp/homebrew20181226-5110-o03zk0.sb nice /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -W0 -I /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-macho-2.1.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rubocop-rspec-1.30.1/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rubocop-0.61.1/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/unicode-display_width-1.4.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/ruby-progressbar-1.10.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/rainbow-3.0.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/powerpack-0.1.2/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/plist-3.4.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/parser-2.5.3.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/parallel-1.12.1/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.1/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/jaro_winkler-1.5.1:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.11.4/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/ast-2.4.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.5/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.6/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-1.3.0/lib:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle-standalone/bundler/../ruby/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.4/lib:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0/lib:/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0:/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin17:/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/universal-darwin17:/Library/Ruby/Site:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin17:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin17:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin17:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin17:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew -- /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/build.rb /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/martindelille/homebrew-tap/pouet.rb` exited with 1.
```

Comment: Looks like you `sha256` is incorrect.

Comment: It should be correct because if I remove it it complains about the `sha256` as expected.

Comment: Please don’t use the [tag:brew] tag for Homebrew-related question. I edited your question to use the proper tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of two issues:

1. There is an error in your formula.
2. Homebrew's error reporting was accidentally broken three days ago.

So, Homebrew tries to report the error in your formula, but then runs into a bug in its own error reporting.

It seems that your SHA-256 checksum is not matching. Therefore, Homebrew tries to report the error, but then runs into [this bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/5443) which was [introduced three days before you wrote your question](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/b7d84f2d9e6b0c44c712dab7987ee3244f80062a#diff-043c6ff4bb5eb7aa62bf74651a88cabfR205) and [was fixed three hours after](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/5444).

To fix this,

1. You need to fix the error in your formula (correct the SHA-256 checksum, or figure out why the checksum does not match the downloaded file)
2. Wait until the bug is fixed and update Homebrew, to get proper error reporting back.